# Mount USB then NFS

Tags: boot, pi-4, ubuntu, nfs

I'm creating a kubernetes cluster with 1 desktop pc and 3 raspberry pi4.

The desktop PC is set as master node and NFS server.

Each RPi4 has two USB keys:

- Ubuntu 21.04 Server on 32GB key
- Storage on 256 GB key

I want to mount a NFS directory on boot on the 256GB

My `/etc/fstab` file looks like this

```
LABEL=writable                                  /               ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro   0    1
LABEL=system-boot                               /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults                    0    1
UUID=2867ec74-ba7c-490c-87ed-096e029f2147       /storage        ext4    defaults                    0    2
192.168.1.10:/mnt/storage/node1                 /storage        nfs     defaults                    0    0
```

Each node has its own directory `node1`, `node2`, `node3`.

The problem here is the mounting of NFS works if I set local path to `/mnt` but doesn't work on start when I set it to `/storage`

This command works `sudo mount 192.168.1.10:/mnt/storage/node1 /storage` but the directory is not mounted on boot.

My theory is on startup, it doesn't have time to mount NFS because the USB storage is not mounted when command is executed.

Can someone confirm ?
If so, does someone have a solution ?

I tried to mount it using cron but it doesn't work.

Comment: You appear to be attempting to mount 2 devices at the same mount point - which is impossible.

Comment: It works when I do it manually `sudo mount 192.168.1.10:/mnt/storage/node1 /storage`

Comment: Another question. Let's say my NFS directory is 500GB, what happens if I mount it on a 32GB USB Key ?

Comment: nothing unusual happens ... you still can't mount two devices to the same mount point - which device do you expect to see in your setup - hint: it'll be the first one